# HTML- Forms to the Server?

Tags: html, forms, server

I am still a beginner in HTML and start now with forms and I have a Question about that.

I know that HTML Forms are one of the main points of interaction between user/web site/application. They allow users to send data to the web site. Most of the time that data is sent to the web server, but the web page can also intercept it to use it on its own.

Can all the information from the forms be sent directly to the server? 
If not, what are the limitations?

Best regards

Comment: This is a better question for an HTML forum, not so much for stack overflow.  Depending on how you configure your application, yes all the form "information" or fields can be sent to the server, where they need to be handled on that end as well (usually a database mapping, perhaps a flat file for simple constructs).  They allow the users to send data to the server.  It also allows for call to the server to populate data into the form.  It is two way (not necessarily bound that way).

Answer (score 0):

By default data from forms is translated into HTTP parameters and is send to the server with a HTTP request. The exact way the value of the parameters is determined depends the element in question. There are options for client-side form validation that could prevent a form submit using certain rules, this can be done using HTML's build in form validation or JavaScript, but by default all data from forms can be send no matter the actual value.

I highly recommend you check out this guide for further details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Or at least this section which roughly describes how the data is transferred to the server:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data